# Displaying Data on Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a question.I have an empty `<table>` and when i click on an empty `<td>`-Element, i can pass Data from an `<input>`-Element and save this String into my Database.Actually i want this String to be displayed on my `<td>`-Element.(It means,there is a possibity, that every `<td>`-Elements can display its own String.)

This is how i create my `<table>` :

```
<tbody>
    <%for(int uzeit = 0; uzeit < uhrzeit.length ;uzeit++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%out.println(uhrzeit[uzeit]); %></td>
            <%for(int rest =0; rest<wochentag.length;rest++) { %>
                <td class="td_test"></td>
            <%} %>
        </tr>
    <%} %>
</tbody>
```

This is how i save the `<input>` :

```
int result = 0;

if(request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
    String name = new String();

    if(request.getParameter("getdata") != null) {
        name = request.getParameter("getdata");     
    }else {
        out.println("termin is null");
    }
    Termin t1 = new Termin();
    result = t1.setTermin(name);

setTermin(name) adds ’name’ to my Database.
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand it correctly, but I think the idea is to have an input field and then, ehn you click on a `td` the data in the input field goes there. To do that, you can use plain JS or Jquery. I used jquery as the code is faster to write. Your change code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function(){
        $(this).text($('#myIn').val());
        $('#myIn').val("");
    });
});
```

Check it working on: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/sn0x6xat/

Basically, when you click a td element, you want it to take the value of the actual input. If what you want is to, also, submit that input, then you can feel free to do it using AJAX while showing the input to the user.

Sorry if I did not answer your question. If I didn't please try to be a little more clear.

Comment: hi, i used the same Jquery before, but its not working, the string shows up for like 0,5 seconds and then disappears from then <td>-Element

Comment: It shouldn't disappear unless you click the <td> while the input is empty...  Did you check the fiddle? It doesn't disappear at all.

Comment: In your fiddle it doesnt disappear, but it seems that in my Code everytime i send the data to the database, the string inside <td> disappears.EDIT:Ok i confirm, that if i dont use <form></form> , everything works fine.

Comment: Then that might mean that you're actually submiting the form. Try to avoid submiting and try again. If possible, please post your full form so that I can try to do something about it.

Comment: yes i would but the code is very huge and i dont know how to display code in the comments.But i figured out what the problem is.Since i use a HttpServlet , i need to rebuild my JSP page with the new Data.(i think)